# SpringMVC - Hibernate: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Group.java**

```
package com.keating.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_group")
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "creatorUUID", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private User creator;

    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
    private Date time = new Date();

    public Group() {
    }

    public Group(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Group(String name, String description, User creator) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public User getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(User creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

And there is my method.

```
public Group getInfo(String groupUUID) {
    String hql = "SELECT group.uuid, group.name, group.description, group.time FROM Group group WHERE group.uuid=?";
    Query query = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter(0, groupUUID);

    return (Group) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

And I think it is ok, but there are some exceptions:

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Errorh1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

**Type** Exception Report

**Message** Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.keating.model.Group

**Description** The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.keating.model.Group
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

**Root Cause**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.keating.model.Group
    com.keating.dao.impl.GroupDaoImpl.getInfo(GroupDaoImpl.java:26)
    com.keating.service.impl.GroupServiceImpl.getInfo(GroupServiceImpl.java:23)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getInfo(Unknown Source)
    com.keating.controller.GroupController.getInfo(GroupController.java:56)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

**Note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/9.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the list of fields you're trying to lookup

```
String hql = "FROM Group group WHERE group.uuid=?";
```

Comment: Yeah,it works.But how to select fields?Some filed I don't want to show.

Comment: then don't display them on your console/output area